# Enable/Disable Single Field Programatically in SOLine

Tags: acumatica

I know that using

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled(sender, e.Row, false);
```

disables an entire row for SOLine. Is there anything I can use to specifically target which elements within the SOLine that I can disable instead of disabling the entire line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this call...

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLine.myField>(
    sender, e.row, false);
```

Replace SOLine.myField with your field you want to enabled/disable and set your true/false to enable/disable

Comment: Thanks again Brendan! Seems simple enough. Don't know why I didn't see an intelliSense for that syntax.